# VBA - Jet SQL - False error message

Tags: sql, vba

Here's the code:

```vb
SQL = " DROP TABLE [H:\Archive23\SPX.accdb].[SPX_MissingTimes] "  
MsgBox SQL  
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

This code ran without an error message for a week, then, after some changes in unrelated code following it, it started generating this message:

> Microsoft Visual Basic
>   Run-time error '3295':
>   Syntax error in DROP TABLE or DROP INDEX.

This error message is generated AFTER later code has run, as proven by the fact that a later `MsgBox` call executes before the error message.

I call it a "false error message" because the code still works, deleting the table every time.
There are no other DROP statements involved in any code.

I have no idea where to start looking.  Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: `This error message is generated AFTER later code has run, as proven by the fact that a later MsgBox call executes before the error message` - if you mean the MsgBox in that code, then it executes before the code has run. If there is yet another MsgBox after `DoCmd.Run`, then it would be interesting.

Comment: Is the table local to database running the DROP statement as it uses an absolute file path. If not, the table cannot be in use anywhere if attempting to drop it. Try using DROP statement in stored query window or with [DAO's Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx) to get a fuller error message.

Answer (score 0):

GSerg, thanks.  Yes, it is a second, different MsgBox coded after DoCmd.Execute that pops up before the error message.  This second msgbox displays the SQL statement for a make-table query which replaces the deleted table, and which is executed without incident.  I probably should have mentioned:  I am using Windows 10 and Access 2016 in a standalone installation (without the rest of Office).  I have had no other strange problems.  I have a suspicion this is related somehow to Access inner threading logic.  Or maybe it's an Access "ghost" (it wouldn't be my first), which can be eliminated by creating a new blank database and importing everything form the afflicted one so start clean.

Comment: Technically, this is not an answer. Do note you can reply to commenters in comments section. But reserve this space for actual answers.